# Print boundaries of one layer over another

Tags: qgis, layers, print-composer

i am new to QGIS. I have a base map from google, openstreet map over which i want to show the boundaries of another layer. How can i do that?

While trying to edit, is it possible that QGIS allows to lay emphasize on the boundary of one layer over the base map of the google maps?